# Centering DIV using any means necessary

Tags: html, centering, css

I know that centering things using CSS has been asked a bunch of times, and I've looked at these, but no matter what I do I can't seem to have my div just neatly centered.

My div is simple enough

```
<div id="overlay">
   <img src="~/Content/images/loading.gif" id="img-load" />
</div>
```

I have a table below this that contains some info.  Yeah, I know tables aren't for arranging, etc.  I know.

```
<table id="uploadTable" style="width:100%;">
<tr valign="top">
    <td width="100%">
        something in here
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        something in here
    </td>    
</tr>
```

After this table declaration I have the jQuery that does the actual determining the width and placement of the overlay.  Works ok, but not always perfectly, and never not on my mobile Android device (always on left margin of where the div lives).

```
<script>           
    $table = $("#uploadTable");                

    $("#overlay").css({
        opacity: 0.9       
        // current 'busy' logo has width of 200, so need to offset width by half that.
        ,left:  (($table.outerWidth()- 100)/2)
        });
</script>
```

My CSS for my overlay is this:

```
#overlay { 
display:none;     
position:absolute; 
background:#fff; 
z-index: 10;  }
```

So, the only way I was able to get this to be centered (mostly) is to use some math, as shown in the ("#overlay").css code.

Everything I try always puts the graphic at the very far left of the parent location 
I've tried margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;
I've tred jquery.position()

Anyone see anything that obviously wrong here?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about centering a modal like this? I have a CodePen sketch: http://cdpn.io/BuDLo

Comment: I think it isn't working on Android because the div is wider than the screen, therefore you're trying to set a negative left. AFAIK you can't set a negative left with anything that isn't `position:relative`

Comment: kunalbhat - Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Kunalbhat, thanks!

http://codepen.io/kunalbhat/full/BuDLo

Use two separate divs, one for the overlay, and one for the graphic that will sit on top of this.  I used jQuery.fadeIn & fadeOut for changing the display to visible/invisible.  Thanks again!

Here's my CSS:

```
#modal-overlay {
  background: gray;
  opacity: .75;
  display:none;     
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:10;
}




#modal-box {
  display:none;     
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index:15;
}
```